# angularjs Ionic and global variables: best practice to make a variable available globally

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to Angular/Ionic.
Before using Angular/Ionic, at the launch of my app, I was checking if we were under Phonegap or a browser using and storing this information in a global boolean variable and then checking if the app was online or offline and storing it to a global variable too, like this :

```
var isPhoneGap;
var connectionStatus;
isPhoneGap = checkIfPhoneGap();

//later in the code :

connectionStatus = checkIfOnline();

function checkIfPhoneGap() {
    var app = document.URL.indexOf( 'http://' ) === -1 && document.URL.indexOf( 'https://' ) === -1; // && document.URL.indexOf( 'file://' );
    if ( app ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function checkIfOnline() {  
    if ( isPhoneGap ) {
        if (checkConnection() == "none" ) {
            connectionStatus = 'offline'; 
        } else {
            connectionStatus = 'online';
        }
        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
            //console.log('Connection : ' + Connection);
            //console.log('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
            return networkState;
        }
    } else {
        connectionStatus = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
    }
    return connectionStatus;
}
```

Now I would like to do the same with Angular/Ionic, I understand that I have to use a "Service". But is it the best way to make this information available through all the code ?

I am doing the following, but is it the "best practice" ?

in index.html :

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

in services.js :

```
angular.module('SnowBoard.services', [])

.factory('isPhoneGap', function() {

    var appp = document.URL.indexOf( 'http://' ) === -1 && document.URL.indexOf( 'https://' ) === -1; // && document.URL.indexOf( 'file://' );
    if ( appp ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

})

;
```

in app.js :

```
angular.module('SnowBoard', ['ionic', 'SnowBoard.controllers', 'SnowBoard.services'])

.run(["isPhoneGap","$ionicPlatform", function(isPhoneGap, $ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

  //CHECK IF ONLINE
  connectionStatus = checkIfOnline(isPhoneGap);

  //DEBUG
  //var debugOptionUseLocalDB=0;
  //updateProDB(connectionStatus, debugOptionUseLocalDB);
}])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
//...all state configurations
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
//...
});
```

This works for now, but I need the boolean `isPhoneGap` to be available everywhere I need it (almost everywhere in my app).

Can you converge to the best practice to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not set variables using `$rootScope`, and try to refrain from using `$scope` as much as possible. Using `LocalStorage` is okay, but this data will persist. I would recommend setting up a factory to store and retrieve variables using `SessionStorage`. `SessionStorage` is tied to the tab you have open, so the data is gone when it is closed.

This is one of my session storage services. I throw `$cookieStorage` in case local storage isn't available. Also, localStorage can only store strings. This is why you will see me converting objects and arrays to and from JSON as needed. After injecting `sessionService`, I need only call `sessionService.store(name, data)` to store a session variable or `sessionService.persist(name, data)` to store persistent data i.e. userName if "Remember Me" is checked. :

```
.service('sessionService', ['$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {
    var localStoreAvailable = typeof (Storage) !== "undefined";
    this.store = function (name, details) {
        if (localStoreAvailable) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(details)) {
                details = null;
            } else if (angular.isObject(details) || angular.isArray(details) || angular.isNumber(+details || details)) {
                details = angular.toJson(details);
            };
            sessionStorage.setItem(name, details);
        } else {
            $cookieStore.put(name, details);
        };
    };

    this.persist = function(name, details) {
        if (localStoreAvailable) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(details)) {
                details = null;
            } else if (angular.isObject(details) || angular.isArray(details) || angular.isNumber(+details || details)) {
                details = angular.toJson(details);
            };
            localStorage.setItem(name, details);
        } else {
            $cookieStore.put(name, details);
        }
    };

    this.get = function (name) {
        if (localStoreAvailable) {
            return getItem(name);
        } else {
            return $cookieStore.get(name);
        }
    };

    this.destroy = function (name) {
        if (localStoreAvailable) {
            localStorage.removeItem(name);
            sessionStorage.removeItem(name);
        } else {
            $cookieStore.remove(name);
        };
    };

    var getItem = function (name) {
        var data;
        var localData = localStorage.getItem(name);
        var sessionData = sessionStorage.getItem(name);

        if (sessionData) {
            data = sessionData;
        } else if (localData) {
            data = localData;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        if (data === '[object Object]') { return null; };
        if (!data.length || data === 'null') { return null; };

        if (data.charAt(0) === "{" || data.charAt(0) === "[" || angular.isNumber(data)) {
            return angular.fromJson(data);
        };

        return data;
    };

    return this;
}])
```

$cookieStore is part of ngCookies. Make sure you have angular-cookies.js included and load ngCookies as you would any module. [Angular ngCookies](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ngCookies)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But isn't there a way to use some kind of "Global variable" with angular ? I mean these variables, I need them everywhere in the code (and in several tabs too).

Comment: Yes, there is. No, you shouldn't use it. Javascript does not lend well to globals. The best practice is to use a factory or service to share data between controllers. The hack is to use $rootScope.

Comment: I just updated your code, because there was an error in the if else.  And now I have another error from angular : `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookieStoreProvider <- $cookieStore <- sessionService <- updateProDB` can you help me fix it ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. $cookieStore is part of ngCookies. Make sure you have angular-cookies.js included and load ngCookies as you would any module. https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ngCookies

Comment: indeed, I have included and loaded ngCookies.  I get a new error from your code. When I try to .store, I get the error : `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at Object.toJson (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8746:15)
    at store (http://localhost:8100/js/services.js:229:35)`   from the line : `details = angular.toJson(details);`...it seems this is because in the object I am trying to store there is an angular thing : `weightunit: select#weightunit.ng-pristine.ng-valid` ... can you help please ?

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'm pretty new to both Ionic and Angular, however I had the same problem with my web app Angular and I have done following to get it working

1. assign variables to `$rootScope`, that way it's visible to all the controllers
2. assign variables to `$scope` , which is visible by current context. Ex: controller and the html pages uses that controller
3. [localStorageService](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), because this will hold the values even after user refreshes the page.

Again please note, this is what I did in my Angular web app and might not be the best practices, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: $rootScope is working fine with me (storing the service URI address) . But what is the difference between $rootScope and window.localStorage.setItem ??

Comment: The difference is that, localStorage data will persist even when the app is closed util explicitly cleared. But, the rootScope value is lost as soon as the page is refreshed/closed.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods available in ionic.Platform that assist in getting back the data you need in regards to the device type.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

You could alternatively look at adding ngCordova, which has a bunch of useful wrappers around cordova plugins, including the device plugin.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Device

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, my question was not really on how to detect the device, because I am pretty happy with my function. But it was more on how to make the boolean variable available everywhere to the code, a bit like a global variable. I've edited my question.